# Inconsistent mining profitability calculations

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-theory, hashpower

I am gathering some btc details from [coinwarz api](https://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/documentation) as follows

Bitcoin difficulty: `711697198174`

Bitcoin reward: `12.5`

My personal hash rate: `1.425 TH/s`

I then try to calculate  amount of seconds it would take me to mine 1 coin, so

```
(711697198174 / 100) / 1.425 = 499436630297
```

The reason I am dividing difficulty by `100` above is so I can keep using my hashing power in TH/s

After this I try to calculate how many coins I can mine per day:

```
86400 / 499436630297 * 12.5 = 0.0002162436502
```

where `86400` is number of seconds in 24h. I get `0.0002162436502` coins per day, however every calculator I used online returns value similar to `0.00050348` coins per day.

I think this `0.00050348` is correct value, but I don't understand where my calculation is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the correct conversions:

> The reason I am dividing difficulty by `100` above is so I can keep using my hashing power in TH/s

There are 1,000 GH to a TH.

> difficulty / hashrate[GH/s] = time[s]

difficulty and hashrate stand in the [following ratio](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5556/5406):

```
difficulty = hashrate[H/s] / 7158388.055
```

Note that the formula uses hashes not gigahashes.