# difficulty value vs. computational power

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-theory, miner-configuration, difficulty, difficulty-retargetting

Assume a miner has a computational power q while the rest of the network has a computational power p = q-1.

Based on [Relationship between Hash-Rate and Difficulty](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/relationship-between-hash-rate-and-difficulty): difficulty = hashrate / 7158388.055.

How are p and q related to that?

What I am trying to figure out is, assuming we have a miner that has 50% of computational power, will the difficulty value change so that miner still finds a block in 10 minutes?

If that is the case, won't that difficulty value be too high for the miners that have much smaller computational power?

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to figure out is, assuming we have a miner that has 50% of computational power, will the difficulty value change so that miner still finds a block in 10 minutes?

The difficulty value will change so that a block is found, on average, every ten minutes.

> If that is the case, won't that difficulty value be too high for the miners that have much smaller computational power?

Each miner will still have a probability of finding a block proportional to their hashing power.

Say you're a miner who finds a block every 30 minutes -- you'll be finding roughly one out of three blocks. If the difficulty doubles, you will now find a block every 60 minutes -- you'll be finding roughly one out of every six blocks.