# How to calculate coins mined per day?

Tags: difficulty, earnings, math

Sorry for the noob question I'm pretty new to crypto coins and all this stuff. :)

I wonder why the formula `<your hashrate> / <coin difficulty>` gives the mined coins as a result...

---

Formula mentioned on [xmg.minerclaim.com](https://xmg.minerclaim.net/index.php?page=statistics&action=pool)
**Quote:**

> "XMG/Day" is calculated by the current Hashrate/Difficulty. Due to the
>   fact that difficulty is constantly changing, this is only a rough
>   estimate.

---

Example ([from altcoin Coin Magi](https://xmg.minerclaim.net/index.php?page=statistics&action=pool)):

If I have a hashrate of 3.211 MH/s and the coins difficulty is 2.599 (approximately) then my earnings per **second** (because it's H/s) should be

> 3,211,000 / 2.599 = ~1235.47 coins per second

and

> 1235.47 * ( 60 * 60 *24 ) = 106744608 coins per day

How can this be? The 'fastest' miner (highest hashrate) has 3.211 MH/s and is 'only' earning 32.892 XMG per day?

Did I do something wrong? Is minerclaim wrong? And what's a good formula to calculate mined coins per day?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Average coins/day for a miner can be estimated by comparing the miner's hashrate with the hashrate of the network.

[image: Cm/day = subsidy * (1440 / blocktime) * (Hm / Hn)]

where,

`Cm` is total coins for the miner
`subsidy` is the number of coins/block a miner gets as a reward
`blocktime` is the average time per block
`Hm` is the miner's hashrate (Hash/sec)
`Hn` is the total network hashpower (Hash/sec)
`1440` is minutes per day

#### Bitcoin

Since the total network hashpower is unknown, it must be estimated based on the current difficulty. This can be done by noting that Difficulty `D`

[image: D=hashrate/7158388.055]

Because

```
difficulty = hashrate / (2^256 / max_target / intended_time_per_block) 
           = hashrate / (2^256 / (2^208*65535) / 600)
           = hashrate / (2^48 / 65535 / 600) 
           = hashrate / 7158388.055
```

see [Relationship Between Hashrate and Difficulty](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5557/60443)

So, for bitcoin given a current difficulty of `5,949,437,371,610` an Antminer S9 with a hashrate of about 14TH/s:

[image: Hn = 5,949,437,371,610 * 7158388.055 = 42,588,381 TH/s]

[image: Cm/day = 12.5 * (1440 / 10) * (14e12 / 42588381e12) = 0.00059171068]

**Note**: This is an average value, so with a large enough pool and enough days, your earnings will average to this formula (this does not account for the difficulty and network hashpower changing, of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Everything's clear now. But one question: D=hashrate/7158388.055 what is 7158388.055 in this formula?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5557/60443

Comment: `Cm/day = subsidy * (1440 / blocktime) * (Hm/Hn)` seems wrong to me, because hash ratio is represented in `Hash/Sec`, but `1440` factor is number of minutes in day. To get true result of mined coin in 24h, we need to change `minutes/day factor` into `seconds/day factor` which is `86400`

Comment: Hash ratio Hm/Hn is unitless. Block time is in minutes thus 1440 min/day